# fread returning 0 when reading a sector from Linux disk

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to read a sector from **/dev/sda** disk on Ubuntu but fread is always returning 0 and i can't seem to understand why it's doing that,
Here's the code that reads the sector :

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

 void read_sector(char *physical_disk, int num_sec) {
     char *diskName = "/dev/";
     char *ch1 = strstr(physical_disk,"sd");
     char *ch2 = strstr(physical_disk,"hd");
     if((ch1==NULL) && (ch2 == NULL)) {
        printf("Error, that is not a physical disk's name. \n");
        }
     else {
           int sect,n;
           int len = strlen(diskName) + strlen(physical_disk) + 2;
           char *str = (char*)malloc(len);
           strcpy(str,diskName);
           unsigned char buffer[512];
           long int sec = 512*num_sec;
           FILE *disk = NULL;
           strcat(str, physical_disk);
           disk = fopen(diskName, "rb");
           if (disk==NULL) printf("error, disk can't be opened \n");
           else {
                 sect = fseek(disk, sec, SEEK_SET);
                 if(sect != 0) printf("fseek error %d \n", sect);
                 else {
                       n = fread(buffer,512,1,disk);                        
                       if(n<=0) printf("fread error %d \n", n);
                       else printf("number of elements read : %d \n", n);
                      }
                }
                fclose(disk)
          }

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  read_sector("sda", 3);
  return(0);
}
```

any ideas on why it's returning 0? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Check `errno`. Please post real compilable source code, without typos, properly formatted, including `int main()` and relevant `#include`s.

Comment: done posting the real source code, thanks

Comment: also, i've checked errno and it's displaying 21, this apparently means "Is a directory" but i have no clue on what it's actually referring to

Comment: Don't add "RESOLVED" to the title. By accepting an answer, you already have marked your question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not compiled this code as it's just snippet . But do you have permission to actually read the device?

you can do this with the following commands.

```
id

uid=1001(user) gid=1001(user) groups=1001(user),27(sudo)

user@host01:~$ ls -la /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 0 Jun 1 01:46 /dev/sda

user@host01:~$ dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null

dd: failed to open '/dev/sda': Permission denied
```

if you ruled out permission, then we can look further at the code.

Comment: i've just executed these commands and Permission denied indeed x)

Comment: is there a way to fix that? sorry to bother you

Comment: Either give yourself permission or run your program with sudo

Comment: I did try to run the program with sudo, same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `fread()`. It should be `buffer`, not `buffe`.

Comment: @TheUnixJanitor, maybe it didn't.

Comment: my bad the typo was in the post only not in the code as i couldn't copy paste it from my VM